# How to display a list in two rows?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a list of items that I want to fit in a space that is constrained vertically:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Since I don't want the list to have more than a specific height, but I'm free to expan it horizontally, I want to divide the list into columns, like this:

```
One    Two     Three
Four   Five    Six
```

Or, alternatively (in my case order is not important)

```
One    Three   Five
Two    Four    Six
```

The css property `column-count` allows to break a list into columns, but it only accepts a fixed number of columns. I don't know the number of items I am going to have (it can go from 1 to more than 40), so if I set the number of columns to 3, any list with more than 6 items will be too high, and if there is only 4 items, then only the first column will have two items and it will look uneven.

So, ideally I would need a `row-count` property, but it doesn't exist. I guess I can do that in Javascript too but I'm looking for a CSS-only solution.

I tried something: `float:left` on every `li` puts the list in one row. To break it into two rows, I would need to *not* apply `float:left` to the N/2 element. I don't know how to do that.

I know also that I can do it by breaking it into multiple `ul`, each one with two `li`, and `float:left` them, but I would like to avoid messing the HTML for something entirely presentational.

Does someone has a solution for this problem?

**Edit:** I think I have not been clear in explaining my requirements. I want the list to be sorted into columns without knowing how many items I'm going to have, and *so that I will always have two rows*.

So for example with 7 items, I want to have:

```
One    Two     Three   Four
Five   Six     Seven
```

And with 3 items:

```
One    Two
Three
```

Comment: @JoshPowell: I discussed that: I don't know the number of items I am going to have, so `column-count` will make me have more than two rows if there are 7 items or more.

Comment: Ahh I see I see, so you want a endless amount of rows to best fit the content, right?

Comment: See my edit: I always want two rows, and as many columns as necessary.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try some ideas out.

Comment: This can't be done in CSS; you need javascript. But it's a good question so upvoted. You need the right tool for the job.

Comment: Well, if it can't be done in CSS, I'm going to accept the Javascript answer, of course. (I still let people some more time to give alternative answers if they want)

Comment: @frenchie For sure it can be done with CSS [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28472713/607874)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it using jquery. I know it is mentioned that a CSS way is needed, but this is just for future reference if anyone wants to refer to this question.

Get the number of LI items and divide it by the number of rows and set that value to column-count property.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var numitems =  $("#myList li").length;

$("ul#myList").css("column-count",Math.round(numitems/2));
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  width: 900px;
}
li {
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myList">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
<li>Seven</li>
<li>Eight</li>
<li>Nine</li>    
</ul>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/H2AsM/1/)

**EDIT:**

Same implementation using simple javascript.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("myList");
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
var numItems = li.length;

var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = "ul { column-count: " + Math.round(numItems/2) + "; }";
document.body.appendChild(css);
```

You need to set the width of UL, because number of rows will depend on the width also even after setting the column-count. You can set it to 100% too, but then the number of rows will change based on the window size. To restrict the number of rows to 2, fixed width for UL may be required.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer a CSS solution, but if that's not possible a simple JS will do :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to use simple javascript instead of jquery, in case you decide to go ahead with this approach :) However I haven't tested the javascript approach very well, you might have to play with it a little bit to get it to work as expected.

Comment: it only worked for me, when I converted the column-count number to a string, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You could set your li at 33% width and floating against each other, once there isn't enough room in a row they will be pushed down in rows of 3 of equal width.

```
ul li{
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: If I have 7 or more items, this would break into more than two rows, no ?

Comment: This one would never break, it will even break the 6 itemed list to 3 lines!

Comment: if you have 7 items you would have 3 rows, 2 full rows of 3 items and 1 row with the remaining one item, dividing the the number of items by 3, rounding up the decimals will give you your number of rows

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is 7 years old but if anyone has similar problem today, then here's a solution using CSS Grid Layout (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/)

```
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help ♥ :)

Comment: This answer works for three rows. If you want for example two rows, change the 3 into a 2.

Answer (score 2):

Why not give it a `max-width`?

```
ul {
  max-width: somevalue; // which would last when the third item ends
}
```

Or, you can add class to them as

```
<ul>
    <li class="one">One</li>
    <li class="one">Two</li>
    <li class="one">Three</li>
    <li class="two">Four</li>
    <li class="two">Five</li>
    <li class="two">Six</li>
</ul>
```

Now CSS as:

```
.one {
  display: inline;
}

.two {
  display: inline;
}
```

The last thing of the padding is as

```
ul li {
  padding: somevalue;
}
```

And for slicing:

```
ul {
  max-width: 200px; // to break the list
}
```

The good luck for you would be that you can first check the width of the list! And then slice it into two equal parts using JS, and then applying it.

If you want to get the CSS calucator, then use this:

```
width: calc(var1 + var2); // calc will do the math..
```

Here is the fiddle for this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/xN87Q/

Comment: I have told you brother! :) You can have the function to do the calcuation, or you can use JS to get the child value! Let say, 7! Then you can increase the `max-width` to `230px`..:)

Comment: Ah, I see I'm going to try that, even if I would have preferred something CSS-only.

Comment: Ok, wait ! I have a new fiddle for you, where if you add more content You still get the lists in a number of 3 :) Wait..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/xN87Q/1/ Here, try this: You will see 7 elements are aligned one under the other ..

Comment: Yes, its a three row answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` to change the ordering from columns to rows:

```css
#list-1 {
  border: 3px solid red;
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

#list-2 {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  columns: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto; /* can change this */
  width: 200px;
}

#list-2 li {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-1">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
<li>g</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list-2">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
<li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
li:nth-child(even) 

li:nth-child(odd)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nCmZT/

Comment: ahh... i see... to use this method the only way to guarantee only 2 rows is to give the ul a specific height, which you will have (per the question). in my fiddle, the UL does not have a height.

Comment: Setting the height of the ul does not change the fact there are still three rows: http://jsfiddle.net/nCmZT/2/

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Creating a two column Unordered List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005407/creating-a-two-column-unordered-list)

Fiddle : [Demo provided in the link](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/4PdQw/)

**HMTL**

```
<ul class="two-col-special">
    <li>First Category</li>
    <li>Second Category</li>
    <li>Third Category</li>
    <li>Fourth Category</li>
    <li>Fifth Category</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.two-col-special {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.two-col-special li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top; /* In case multi-word categories form two lines */
}
.two-col-special li:before {
    content: '+';
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px; /* you can tweak the gap */
    color: orange;
    background-color: white; /* in case you want a color... */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I don't want a fixed number of columns, but a fixed numbers of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easies and proper  way {OL tag especially} would be:

```
<ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
      <li>Six</li>
    </div>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just, **no**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755657/2123530

Comment: div's inside ul's are totally legit in HTML5 and you won't be hurting anything, most of the modern browser will render with no issue so its honestly that easy. You can even wrap block elements in anchor tags, its awesome

Comment: No. The specification explicitly says you cannot. Even in HTML 5. See the answer linked above.