# Change list arrangement - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got list like below

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

How do make the list arrangement to like this.

```
 1  2    5  6    9  10
 3  4    7  8   11  ....etc
```

or

```
 1  3    5  7     9 11
 2  4    6  8    10 .... etc
```

I need this arrangement because i'm using angular `ng-repeat`, so i need every number has the same element. I dont mind if you guys give the answer using other element, but every number must have same element. Thanks

p/s: the number will increase when scroll, like infinite scroll.

Comment: Would you be having more no. of `li`? If yes, what should be the order for them?

Comment: I think you can do it using your custom orderBy filter [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat).  Just that I will need to figure out the formula for the series. Do you have already?

Comment: @Harry, i update the question, it will be a lot of `li` with the same order.

Comment: @amitthk..i also figure that out but didn't have the formula yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a list in two rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570359/how-to-display-a-list-in-two-rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split your content into 2 columns.

```css
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 30%;
    -moz-column-gap: 30%;
    column-gap: 30%;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35%; /* (parent 100% - parent gap 30%) / columns */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

The solution above works when you have 8 or less `li` items.

But if the number of items is unknown, you can place a class to figure out the number of columns.
For example, consider you have in your angular model a variable `qtItems`. You can do something like this:

```
<ul ng-class = "'col' + Math.ceil(qtItems/4)">
```

Then use CSS for each class:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.col2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 30%;
    -moz-column-gap: 30%;
    column-gap: 30%;
}

ul.col2 li {
    width: 35%;
}

ul.col3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20%;
    -moz-column-gap: 20%;
    column-gap: 20%;
}

ul.col3 li {
    width: 20%;
}

ul.col4 {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10%;
    -moz-column-gap: 10%;
    column-gap: 10%;
}

ul.col4 li {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of LI items and divide it by the number of rows and set that value to column-count property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var numitems =  $("#myList li").length;

$("ul#myList").css("column-count",Math.round(8/2)); /*   number of items / row  */
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  width: 25px; /*   200px / 8 = 25px   */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>    
</ul>
```

You need to set the width of UL, because number of rows will depend on the width also even after setting the column-count. You can set it to 100% too, but then the number of rows will change based on the window size. To restrict the number of rows to 2, fixed width for UL may be required.

Credits to [Poornima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570359/how-to-display-a-list-in-two-rows/20570703#20570703)

With some modifíing I could get along with this. It's not what you wanted, but maybe it will help others in need.

Answer (score 0):

you can take two ul in one ul and you can adjust which you exactly want to see.

HTML

```
   <ul class="mainul">
    <li>
        <ul class="subul">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
         <ul class="subul">
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.mainul
{
 list-style-type:none;
}
.subul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.subul li
{
    display:inline;
}
```