# How to break a html list into colums

Tags: jquery, html, css, list

Just wondering if a html list could be break into columns based in its positions (using css and/or jquery)

Let say I want to create as many columns as (TOTAL-ITEMS/3).

**Then in this list I will get 2 columns.**

```
<ul id="list-1" >
  <li>item in first column</li>
  <li>item in first column</li>
  <li>item in first column</li>

  <li>item in second column</li>
  <li>item in second column</li>
  <li>item in second column</li>
</ul>
```

**In this one I'll get 3 columns.**

```
<ul id="list-1">
  <li>item in first column</li>
  <li>item in first column</li>
  <li>item in first column</li>

  <li>item in second column</li>
  <li>item in second column</li>
  <li>item in second column</li>

  <li>item in third column</li>
  <li>item in third column</li>
  <li>item in third column</li>
</ul>
```

Since the list is generated by a CSM I can not add custom classes nor id.

Comment: Considering X the width of the element containing the list, you can give X/3 width to each `<li>` item and displaying them inline. In this way it should escape the list every 3 items...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely  you can add columns like so:

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/49ksywv2/1/)

[**Column-count @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

However, CSS cannot detect the number of `li` to apply a specific number of columns. You would have to determine that some other way.

---

There is a JQuery technique as follows:

Credit to this [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570359/how-to-display-a-list-in-two-rows)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numitems =  $("#myList li").length;    
    $("ul#myList").css("column-count",numitems/3);
    $("ul#myList").css("-webkit-column-count",numitems/3);
    $("ul#myList").css("-moz-column-count",numitems/3);

});
```

**[JSfiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/H2AsM/185/)**

Comment: Do you think the jquery technique would be a good fallback for old browsers?

Comment: I'm no expert on Jquery (I had to do a search to find the previous answer) but I see no reason why not.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `column-count: 3;` to your unordered list

Comment: @Paulie_D: sorry you were first

Answer (score 0):

May I help you.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = $("#list-1 li").length;
  var x = Math.ceil($(count)[0]/3);
  $("#list-1").css({"-webkit-column-count": ''+x, 
                    "-moz-column-count": ''+x,
                    "column-count": ''+x});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list-1">
  <li>item in first column</li>
  <li>item in first column</li>
  <li>item in first column</li>

  <li>item in second column</li>
  <li>item in second column</li>
  <li>item in second column</li>

  <li>item in third column</li>
  <li>item in third column</li>
  <li>item in third column</li>
  
  <li>item in fourth column</li>
</ul>
```