# Why li with 50% width and float left don't show dots on the left

Tags: html, css

I've try to create 2 colums list so I use:

```
ul {
   overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}
```

but when I have 2 items that one on the right have list bullet and the one on the left don't. Why is that?

PS: is there a way to have 2 columns list without using `:before` with `content: "•"`

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/ maybe this helps you

Comment: try adding list-style : disc. By the way, what are you trying to achieve with float? I suggest you try display: inline-block for the li instead of using float.

Comment: @hakiko this make bullets disappear.

Comment: Seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/sqhYQ/). Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @jacelysh list-style is disc by default. I got list but first item don't have bullet only the second one.

Comment: Then I suggest you try display: inline-block for the li instead of using float.

Comment: the code you have given is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/6fwWW/

Comment: @jacelysh inline-block also make bullets disappear. I can solve that with :before to add bullet back in but I know why is bullet disappear.

Comment: @jcubic try only using `dislpay:inline-block` **without floating**.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai weird, why this don't work: `data:text/html,<ul><li>item</li><li>item</li></ul><style>ul { overflow: hidden; } ul li { float: left; width: 50%; }</style>`

Comment: this also working. I think it is happening because of other html part. Can you share the entire html part?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai that's the data uri when I open that data page, I don't see bullets.

Answer (score 0):

The left ones are still having a bullets but you can't see it because of the `float: left;`. I think if you remove it, the problem will dissapear, specially if before that you have a reset `margin: 0; padding: 0;` for all the elements in the current html page.

Comment: this also make bullet disappear: `data:text/html,<ul><li>item</li><li>item</li></ul><style>li { display: inline-block; width: 50%;}</style>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and neither `overflow:hidden` nor `display: inline-block` worked for me.

So I cheated using the unicode number for 'bullet' before all items in my list: `&#8226;`

It's far from elegant, but does the trick in desperate situations.