# Two column list based on data-* attribute

Tags: html, css

It is possible to create a two column appearance in a list based on a data attribute of an element?
My HTML which can't really be modified into two lists (even using JS breaks other functionality on the page) looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li data-list="general_results">general text1</li>
    <li data-list="general_results">general text2</li>
    <li data-list="general_results">general text3</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text1</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text2</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text3</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text4</li>
</ul>
```

I want the output to appear as:

```
general text1               category text1
general text2               category text2
general text3               category text3
                            category text4
```

It is same to assume that the  will always have the elements grouped in order.

I'm not sure how to achieve this with the desired output. Floating places elements in a left to right fashion instead of a vertical layout.
Any ideas?

Comment: so it's like your separating it into two categories?

Comment: Pretty much but only visually. Kinda need it to stay together semantically.

Comment: how about using jquery?. you can do something like this.
`$('ul li[data-list=general_results]').each(function(){

    alert($(this).html());

});`

Comment: I don't see how that splits them visually? If I place these <li>'s into another element or move from where they are, then the other stuff that's already listening to them breaks and I loose that functionality. As it's something built by another person I don't understand how it works which is why I was hoping for a CSS solution

Comment: you need to get the value first.... put it on an array... and do a foreach.. append them on different element. ex. `div`

Comment: I did try that but then the other stuff on the page breaks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005407/creating-a-two-column-unordered-list
I think this will help you

Comment: Check out my answer... hope that's what you're looking for.. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a blank line you can achieve this quite easily using column-count.

```css
div#twoColumn {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="twoColumn">
    <ul>
    <li data-list="general_results">general text1</li>
    <li data-list="general_results">general text2</li>
    <li data-list="general_results">general text3</li>
     <li data-list="general_results">&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text1</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text2</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text3</li>
    <li data-list="category_results">category text4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I do like this solution but although the grouping will always together, the number of each may vary so I can't reliably add or remove to create equal numbers.

Comment: @jharry i dunno how you'll do it then unless you separate them into separate lists? http://jsfiddle.net/14uLept1/

Comment: I did split them into lists via JS but then the issue is that jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did...

HTML CODE.. I get the `data-list` attr value then filter through it and append on different divs.

```
<ul>
<li data-list="general_results">general text1</li>
<li data-list="general_results">general text2</li>
<li data-list="general_results">general text3</li>
<li data-list="category_results">category text1</li>
<li data-list="category_results">category text2</li>
<li data-list="category_results">category text3</li>
<li data-list="category_results">category text4</li>
</ul>

<div id="gen_text_here">
</div>
<br />
<div id="cat_text_here">
</div>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$('ul li').each(function(){

  if($(this).attr("data-list") == 'general_results'){
     $('#gen_text_here').append($(this).attr("data-list") + '<br />');
  }else if($(this).attr("data-list") == 'category_results'){
     $('#gen_text_here').append($(this).attr("data-list")  + '<br />');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution but it does the trick:

```
[data-list="general_results"] {
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qUAT6/1113/

But I don't support this. The right solution is to separate your elements in two lists.